# Is there any reason to escape integers in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, escaping, underscore.js-templating

If I fetch the following object from the server via Ajax:

```
$.get('/product/10', function (response) {
  product = response;
    // product:
    // {
    //   name: "Product X",
    //   stock: 20
    // }
});
```

And then output it to HTML using an Underscore.js template like this:

```
<input type="number" value="<%- product.name %>">
<input type="number" value="<%= product.stock %>">
```

Is there any reason to also escape the `stock` attribute if I know it will always come as an integer from the server?

I can't think of a way to exploit it so I was wondering if an "escape all the things" is a good policy or if an "escape only what you need" is a better one.

Comment: If the value is not an user-input, there is no need to escape it.

Comment: @undefined Escaping is not for preventing XSS. It's because some characters, like quotes, may need to be escaped. Integers don't need it.

Comment: @Juan Mendes It's for both. If you don't sanitize the quotes, you open an XSS vulneratibility. This only applies when user input is involved, but you can easily exploit an unescaped value of a field this way. Example, if I linked you to a vulnerable page, the page might display something like: `"><script>send_your_cookies_to_my_website();</script>` in the "value" field. The quote, and angle bracket, would move the script out of the "value" property.

Comment: @RadGH I didn't explain myself well enough. My point is that even if it's not user input, you still have to escape it or you risk having a quote (or < ) in the string breaking your HTML. Preventing XSS is a side effect of escaping your strings. This comment is an example, we don't want to let the < wreak havoc

Comment: @Juan Mendes Fair enough. As long as other readers understand both sides of escaping data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be completely on the safe side, escape everything. Code may change and you may decide to use a string where you previously used a number. If you escape everything, you won't have a problem.

However, that is just being cautious. If you can guarantee that it will always be a number, even when the AJAX request fails, and in all edge cases, then it's OK not to escape it. Note that everywhere I've worked, the consensus was play it safe.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to escape integers obviously. It may be in a good habit to escape everything in general and to print the raw versions of what you intend to. However you can also say you should trust what comes from the server- not what comes from the client. In the end it only matters what you want to get in the habit of. Personally I wouldn't think to escape it (because it doesn't need to be escaped) so I wouldn't escape it.

Comment: I agree with the sentiment. However, everywhere I've worked, we preferred to escape everything to avoid missing some edge cases.

Comment: I'd agree as well that that is probably a better idea. I would go with that.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is dynamically typed, so there is no way to ensure that `product.stock` is really a number by the time it gets to the template. Any code written in the future using the template (possibly written by someone else) could pass any value for `product`, so `stock` could be of any type.

Best to always escape, except in the rare case when you expect the value to actually be HTML, in which case you cannot escape, so that future changes to the code are less likely to break the template.

Comment: Good point, HTML is a case where you shouldn't escape. I prefer never to have the server return HTML, but I understand that's not the way everybody goes

Answer (score 0):

If the input is of type `number` then you're guaranteed to get a number or nothing in that input.

As a test, try adding the string `drop database` to an input of type number. **Spoiler Alert**: The input will stay empty.

Inputs of type `text` can be more dangerous.